# zookeeper- resend message after configured time

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

In my use case, I create a consumer, read messages and write them to elastic search. Then, I commit them (no auto commit).
In certain cases there might be failures in writing, so that I don't commit. Is there an option to configure zookeeper to resend a msg that wasn't sent after a certain amount of time?

Comment: I cannot follow... Zookeeper is a "Distrubted Consesus Service" and does not send messages.... You also tagged this question with "apache-kafka" -- do you consumer messages from there? Please edit your question and give more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Apache Kafka you can change your config for retries properties on your Producer : http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#producerconfigs

Comment: yes, but this is not a case of failure in send- seems like uncommitted msgs are not covered by a configuration